create content page - filter queryset by foreignkey and render the result to Django templates -
Trying to render this structure (tree structure):
Book_1
 Books_1's Chapters
Book_2
 Books_2's Chapters

book:To Kill a Mockingbird
 itschapter:Chapter 1 - The Beginning of the Finch's
 itschapter:Chapter 2 - The Adventures of Education
 ...
book:The Sweet Hereafter
 itschapter:Chapter 1 - Dolores Driscoll
 itschapter:Chapter 2 - Billy Ansel
 ...

I have two Django models(tables) for just that:
two tables with id and name columns.
# myApp/models.py
from django.db import models

# books table #
class books_DB(models.Model):
  #pk is book_id
  book_id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
  book_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# chapters table #
class chapters_DB(models.Model):
  #pk is chapter_id
  chapter_id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
  #foreign key 'book_id' from 'books_DB' 
  book_id = models.ForeignKey(books_DB, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
  chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

I tested how to get this structure in python shell
from .models import *

for x in books_DB.objects.all():
 print(x.book_name)
 for y in x.chapters_db_set.all():
   print(' ' + y.chapter_name)

To Kill a Mockingbird
 The Beginning of the Finch's
 The Adventures of Education
The Sweet Hereafter
 Dolores Driscoll
 Billy Ansel

Now I wish to render the result to a page like this
• To Kill a Mockingbird
  1. The Beginning of the Finch's
  2. The Adventures of Education
• The Sweet Hereafter
  1. Dolores Driscoll
  2. Billy Ansel

<ul class="books">

 <li class="book">To Kill a Mockingbird</li>
   <ol class="chapters">
      <li class="chapter">The Beginning of the Finch's</li>
      <li class="chapter">The Adventures of Education</li>
   </ol>

 <li class="book">The Sweet Hereafter</li>
   <ol class="chapters">
      <li class="chapter">Dolores Driscoll</li>
      <li class="chapter">Billy Ansel</li>
   </ol>

</ul>

I tried
<ul class="books">

    <!-- all_books is books_DB.objects.all() -->
    {% for x in all_books %}
    <li class="book">{{ x.book_name }}</li>
    <ol class="chapters">
        {% for y in x.chapter_db_set.all %}
            <li class="chapter">{{ y.chapter_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>

which gives
book:To Kill a Mockingbird
book:The Sweet Hereafter

so the inner for loop for chapters returns nothing
        {% for y in x.chapter_db_set.all %}
            <li class="chapter">{{ y.chapter_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

but I can't seem to figure out how to use _set.all() in a template within {% %} tags and should I. Or even how to pass data filtered in views.py to the page the right way in this scenario.

chapters_db_set

@willeM_VanOnsem, chapters_db_set raises an error TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable, unfortunately. Thank you for assistance though.

https://github.com/Hasyama/create-content-page if anyone wants the whole code

{% for y in x.chapters_db_set.all %}...

EDITED - FORGET PREVIOUS
your html structure seems a bit wrong.
it should be like this:
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>First numbered Item</p>
        <ol>
            <li>one thing</li>
            <li>two things</li>
            <li>three things</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Second numbered Item</p>
        <ol>
            <li>one thing</li>
            <li>two things</li>
            <li>Three things</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>

so inner ol tag is part of outer li tag
try
<ul class="books">

    <!-- all_books is books_DB.objects.all() -->
    {% for x in all_books %}
        <li class="book">
            <p>{{ x.book_name }}</p>
            <ol class="chapters">
                {% for y in x.chapter_db_set.all %}
                    <li class="chapter">{{ y.chapter_name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ol>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


That worked like a charm. I'm just no good in HTML :D

don't worry - no pythonist is :D (me 2)
